# No module named 'tensorflow.python.training.tracking'

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow

I am trying to analyse my reviews with the absa.ipynb jupyter notebook from this repo: https://github.com/microsoft/nlp-recipes/tree/master/examples/sentiment_analysis/absa

The notebook uses azure ml and python code.

All the specified steps have been followed, I created an virtual environment with all the prerequisite packages. However, when I try to run the script it gives me the error No module named 'tensorflow.python.training.tracking'. I have been searching on Google for a solution, but couldn't find a suitable one.

I tried pip uninstall tensorflow-hub pip install tensorflow-hub==0.7.0, but it didn't worked.

Would be great if we find a solution!